# Ontouchevent for checkbox using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have developed android phonegap app using javascript,html and jquery.I am using dynamic checkboxes and i used click function,but sometimes and in some devices it is very difficult for me to click the checkbox to check and uncheck.Then i changed that into ontouchend but then all the checkbox is clicked.But i need to check any one in the group.What is the solution for this.

Here is my code:

```
$("input[type='checkbox'][name='"+$(this).attr('name')+"']").live('touchend',function() {

    var currentAnswer=this;
     $("input[name='"+$(this).attr('name')+"']").attr('checked', false);
     currentAnswer.checked=true;
     });
```

Please kindly guide me.Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If you want the click event then you need to use an onclick listener, touch events my become drags or clicks or other gestures. If it's hard to click the element, then your interface is flawed. Try using a label around the associated text to make the "clickable" area bigger, e.g. `<label ...><input type="checkbox" ...> Value</label>`.

Comment: are you using jquery mobile framework?

Comment: @SandeepGB:No I am not using jquery mobile

Comment: Thanks RobG I am using dynamic checkboxes.How can i add label for that...Kindly help me.